# Mongodb db.serverStatus() memory section doesn't show actual value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create a chart regarding to the `db.serverStatus()` output of remote or local mongodb connections.

This command outputs:

```
 "mem": {
    "bits": 64,
    "resident": 258,
    "virtual": 4807,
    "supported": true,
    "mapped": 2288,
    "mappedWithJournal": 4576
  },
```

which perfectly suits my needs. But unfortunately I've realized this data never gets the actual memory data and never change. (I've monitored it for 10 minutes)

Am I doing something wrong ? Or is there any other way to get actual memory usages ?

> p.s. I've examined `mongostat` but I couldn't make it work through meteor-js since it's an executable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the source in which you call `db.serverStatus()` to provide more context?

Comment: It actually doesn't matter, because currently I'm trying this command from mongo shell

Comment: So, let me ask you a question: How did you get your reference values you call the "actual" values?

Comment: I'm comparing values with the top command they don't seem same, furthermore the output of db.serverStatus() never changes, I've tried to query database a few hundred times to check if memory will raise in the output of command, but no chance